# Call specific div, as per input value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call specific div as per the input value. below is the expected result

If type "one" in input filed result should view as "Page one",
If type "two" in input filed result should be "Page two",
If type anything else in input filed result should be "Page three"

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div id="one" name="one" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Page One</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="two" name="two" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Page Two</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="three" name="three" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Page Three</h1>
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="enter" name="enter" value="" />
  <input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="test();">
<script>
function test() {
  var v_input = document.getElementById("enter").value;
  var v_one = "one";
  var v_one = "two";
  if (v_input = v_one) {

    $('#one').show();
    $('#two').hide();
    $('#three').hide();
  } else if (v_input = v_two) {
    $('#one').hide();
    $('#two').show();
    $('#three').hide();
  } else {
    $('#one').hide();
    $('#two').hide();
    $('#three').show();
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Please, advice how to fix this issue, thanks in advance

Comment: You are missing one last bracket in your javascript method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had various little mistakes. Re-assigning `v_one` variable, in if you should use **`==`** instead of **`=`** and you missed a `}`.I think that was all. If you already have jquery cdn defined delete mine.

```
<body>
  <div id="one" name="one" style="display:none;">
<h1>Page One</h1>
</div>

<div id="two" name="two" style="display:none;">
<h1>Page Two</h1>
</div>

<div id="three" name="three" style="display:none;">
<h1>Page Three</h1>
</div>
<input type="text" id="enter"  name="enter" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="test();">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

function test() {
  var v_input = document.getElementById("enter").value;
  var v_one = "one";
  var v_two = "two";
  if (v_input == v_one) {

     $('#one').show();
     $('#two').hide();
     $('#three').hide();
  }else if (v_input == v_two){
     $('#one').hide();
     $('#two').show();
     $('#three').hide();
}else {
      $('#one').hide();
     $('#two').hide();
     $('#three').show();
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the input from your textbox using:

```
const inputText = $("#enter").val();
```

And the you can select a given "page" to show using:

```
$("#" +inputText);
```

If the length of this selected item is `0` (which is fasley) then the page doesn't exist so you can then show the div with the `id` of `three`. If the length of the selected item is not zero (truthy) then that means the selected item exists, and so you can show it using:

```
$("#" +inputText).show();
```

You can also add a `class` called `page` to your `div`'s so you can toggle their visibility more specifically and easily.

See working example below:

```js
const test = function() {
  const inputText = $("#enter").val();
  $('.page').hide(); // hide all open pages (then later we will show the selected one)
  const elemToShow = $("#" +inputText);
  if(!elemToShow.length) {
    $("#three").show();
  } else {
    $("#" +inputText).show();
  } 
}
```

```css
.page {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page" id="one" name="one">
<h1>Page One</h1>
</div>

<div class="page" id="two" name="two">
<h1>Page Two</h1>
</div>

<div class="page" id="three" name="three">
<h1>Page Three</h1>
</div>
<input type="text" id="enter"  name="enter" value="one" />
<input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="test();">
```

Answer (score 0):

probably it is because you re-assign the value of `var v_one`

```js
var v_one = "one";
var v_one = "two";
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove all inline javascript, then remove all inline styles.

Once we have that, give your elements a common class name, so that we can hide them in a single line.

After that, simply take the value and put it into the selector.

```js
$('#btn').on('click', () => {
 const value = $('#enter').val();
  $('.showHide').hide();
  $('#' + value).show();
});
```

```css
.showHide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" name="one" class="showHide">
<h1>Page One</h1>
</div>

<div id="two" name="two" class="showHide">
<h1>Page Two</h1>
</div>

<div id="three" name="three" class="showHide">
<h1>Page Three</h1>
</div>
<input type="text" id="enter"  name="enter" value="" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click here">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in defining the  `v_two`  and in `if ==`

```js
function test() {
var v_input = document.getElementById("enter").value;


var v_one = "one";
var v_two = "two";


if (v_input == v_one) {  

   $('#one').show();
   $('#two').hide();
   $('#three').hide();
}

else if (v_input ==v_two){
   $('#one').hide();
   $('#two').show();
   $('#three').hide();
   
    }
else {
    $('#one').hide();
   $('#two').hide();
   $('#three').show();
}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="one" name="one" style="display:none;">
<h1>Page One</h1>
</div>

<div id="two" name="two" style="display:none;">
<h1>Page Two</h1>
</div>

<div id="three" name="three" style="display:none;">
<h1>Page Three</h1>
</div>
<input type="text" id="enter"  name="enter" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="test();">



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in your JavaScript:

1. Missing the last bracket.
2. Missing assignment of `v_two`.
3. For comparing you have used single equal (`=`) it should be double equals(`==`).

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   function test() {
   var v_input = document.getElementById("enter").value;
   var v_one = "one";
   var v_two = "two";
   if (v_input == v_one) {  

      $('#one').show();
      $('#two').hide();
      $('#three').hide();
   }

   else if (v_input == v_two){
      $('#one').hide();
      $('#two').show();
      $('#three').hide();
       }
   else {
       $('#one').hide();
      $('#two').hide();
      $('#three').show();
   }
   }
   ```

I have updated your javascript hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 function test() {
    var v_input = document.getElementById("enter").value;
    var v_one = "one";
    var v_two = "two";
    // all are hidden
    $('#one').hide();
    $('#two').hide();
    $('#three').hide();

    var nameId = "#three"; // variable to get id or you can keep this as empty
    if (v_input == v_one) {  
       nameId = '#one';
    } else if (v_input == v_two) {
       nameId = '#two'
    } else {
       nameId = '#three'; // you can use this section for default behaviour 
    }

    // Show selected name
    $(nameId).show();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know is it helpful or not

```js
function test() {
  var v_input = document.getElementById("enter").value;
  $('#three ,#one ,#two').hide();

  if (v_input == "one" || v_input == "two") {
    $('#' + v_input).show();
  } else {
    $('#three').show();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" name="one" style="display:none;">
  <h1>Page One</h1>
</div>

<div id="two" name="two" style="display:none;">
  <h1>Page Two</h1>
</div>

<div id="three" name="three" style="display:none;">
  <h1>Page Three</h1>
</div>
<input type="text" id="enter" name="enter" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="test();">
```

Answer (score 0):

What you will need, is a ***two way binding*** in pure java script to achieve your goal.

Here is the basic snippet for your code:

```js
function DataBind(element, data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.element = element;
    element.value = data;
    element.addEventListener("change", this, false);
}

DataBind.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
    switch (event.type) {
        case "change": this.change(this.element.value);
    }
};

DataBind.prototype.change = function(value) {
    this.data = value;
    this.element.value = value;
};

var obj = new DataBind(document.getElementById("enter"), "");

var pageField = obj.element;
pageField.onkeydown = updateNameDisplay;
pageField.onkeyup = updateNameDisplay;
pageField.onkeypress = updateNameDisplay;
function updateNameDisplay() {
    //key down event
}

function test() {
var v_one = "one";
var v_two = "two";
if (obj.element.value === v_one) {  

   $('#one').show();
   $('#two').hide();
   $('#three').hide();
}

else if (obj.element.value === v_two){
   $('#one').hide();
   $('#two').show();
   $('#three').hide();
    }
else {
    $('#one').hide();
   $('#two').hide();
   $('#three').show();
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" name="one" style="display:none;">
<h1>Page One</h1>
</div>

<div id="two" name="two" style="display:none;">
<h1>Page Two</h1>
</div>

<div id="three" name="three" style="display:none;">
<h1>Page Three</h1>
</div>
<input type="text" id="enter" name="enter" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="test();">
```